# rails model creation - skip create if invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This seems easy enough. I'm creating things in batches, boxes, that have a unique ID. there is validation on the database for uniqueness, and at the model level. Is there a quick rails trick to just skip the record if it exists??

**Box controller**

```
def create
  @box = Box.find(params[:box_id])
  start = params[:start].scan(/\d/).join('').to_i
  params[:quantity].to_i.downto(1) do
    UniqueNumber.create(uin: 'ERB' + "%07d" % start, box_id: @box.id, active: true)
    start += 1
  end
  redirect_to @box
end
```

so... if box 561 exists in the database... and I tell the system, start at 500 and add 100 boxes, I'd like it to skip over 561 instead of yelling at me.

I'm thinking of doing it in the controller:

```
params[:quantity].to_i.downto(1) do
  if Box.where(uin: 'ERB' + "%07d" % start).blank?
    UniqueNumber.create(uin: 'ERB' + "%07d" % start, box_id: @box.id, active: true)
    start += 1
  end
end
```

but I can't help thinking there is something built in at the model level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `UniqueNumber` instances contain both a `uin`, `active`, and `box_id` attribute – but you *only* want to validate against the `uin` – you can chain [`create_with`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-create_with) with [`find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) to generate the query you want:

```
UniqueNumber.create_with(box_id: @box.id, active: true).find_or_create_by(uin: 'ERB' + "%07d" % start)
```

**To illustrate**, suppose a `UniqueNumber` with a `uin` of `ERB0000005` already exists:

```
UniqueNumber.first
#=> #<UniqueNumber id: 1, uin: "ERB0000005", box_id: 1, active: true>
```

Assuming it's the only entry in the `unique_numbers` table, the following will be true:

```
# Creates a NEW record
UniqueNumber.create_with(box_id: 2, active: true).find_or_create_by(uin: "ERB0000004")
#=> #<UniqueNumber id: 2, uin: "ERB0000004", box_id: 2, active: true>

# Returns an EXISTING record
UniqueNumber.create_with(box_id: 2, active: true).find_or_create_by(uin: "ERB0000005")
#=> #<UniqueNumber id: 1, uin: "ERB0000005", box_id: 1, active: true>
```

Whether or not you do anything with the returned record (in your case, you shouldn't), you'll only be creating a new record if a `UniqueNumber` with the `uin` being queried against *does not* yet exist. So, in code, you can implement the following:

```
params[:quantity].to_i.downto(1) do
  UniqueNumber.create_with(box_id: @box.id, active: true).find_or_create_by(uin: 'ERB' + "%07d" % start)
  start += 1
end
```

**UPDATE**:

In response to the [OP's follow-up comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915748/rails-model-creation-skip-create-if-invalid/20916683#comment31405416_20916683) to this answer:

> [W]ould this be any different than UniqueNumber.where(uin: 'ERB' + "%07d" % start, box_id: @box.id, active: true).first_or_create

The answer is **yes**, this is decidedly different. Take the following example:

```
# Returns an EXISTING record
UniqueNumber.where(uin: "ERB0000005", box_id: 1, active: true).find_or_create
#=> #<UniqueNumber id: 1, uin: "ERB0000005", box_id: 1, active: true>

# Creates a NEW record – even though it should not
UniqueNumber.where(uin: "ERB0000005", box_id: 2, active: true).find_or_create
#=> #<UniqueNumber id: 3, uin: "ERB0000005", box_id: 2, active: true>
```

You want the second query to return an *existing* record because the `uin` already exists, but it's actually creating a *new* record. Why? Because your `where` clause necessarily matches *all three* attributes – but you *only* want to match against `uin`. So, with `first_or_create`, it's possible that you'll be inadvertently creating multiple `UniqueNumber` objects with the same `uin` value.

*However*, if you were to limit your `where` clause to the `uin` attribute, you *could* pass the remaining attributes to `first_or_create` for creation:

```
# Returns an EXISTING record
UniqueNumber.where(uin: "ERB0000005").find_or_create(box_id: 3, active: true)
#=> #<UniqueNumber id: 1, uin: "ERB0000005", box_id: 1, active: true>

# Creates a NEW record – as it should
UniqueNumber.where(uin: "ERB0000006").find_or_create(box_id: 3, active: true)
#=> #<UniqueNumber id: 4, uin: "ERB0000006", box_id: 3, active: true>
```

In the above instance, chaining `where` with `find_or_create` does effectively the same as chaining `create_with` with `find_or_create_by`. I prefer the latter because it's a bit more clear/explicit what's happening, IMO, but preference between the two probably boils down to an academic distinction.

Comment: I like your explanation... would this be any different than `UniqueNumber.where(uin: 'ERB' + "%07d" % start, 
                         box_id: @box.id, 
                         active: true).first_or_create`?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a response. If you've found my answer helpful in addressing your question, please consider upvoting/accepting it as correct.

Comment: Well said. In my case the box.id will always be associated with a particular uin, so it makes no difference. This type of 'validation' is much clearer now, though, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The method you're suggesting does have an implementation already available to you. Take a look at [`find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) in the rails docs.

A better approach, since you know the range of boxes you're going to create, would be to do a single query for all boxes within the range and then exclude those from your creation loop. This way you'll only need to do a single lookup before beginning your inserts.